# React Native Youtube Video is not playing if not fullscreen

Tags: react-native

I am facing this weird issue, my youtube videos are not playing if the **fullscreen** is set to false. But if I set it to true, then it works fine. I dont need the full screen. Following is my code

```
{this.state.showYoutube &&

    <YouTube
        apiKey="MY-YOUTUBE-API-KEY"
        videoId={this.state.videoId}   // The YouTube video ID
        play={false}             // control playback of video with true/false
        fullscreen={false}       // control whether the video should play in fullscreen or inline
        loop={false}             // control whether the video should loop when ended

        //onReady={e => this.setState({ isReady: true })}
        //onChangeState={e => this.setState({ status: e.state })}
        //onChangeQuality={e => this.setState({ quality: e.quality })}
        //onError={e => this.setState({error: e.error})}
        onError={e => console.log(e.error)}

        style={{alignSelf: 'stretch', height: 300}}
    />

}
```

if `this.state.showYoutube` is set to true then **Youtube** will be shown and the `this.state.videoId` is set after an api call,

I have used height and removed native base drawer after facing overlaying issue. Then it was working.

But now it is not working again, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: could you try to delete the whole fullscreen line, because fullscreen is set default as false.

Comment: I have tried that, did not work. Also I have tried removing the play and loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](https://github.com/inProgress-team/react-native-youtube/issues/131#issuecomment-314456875)

```
export default class extends Component {
    state = {
        height: 215
    }

    handleReady = () => {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ height: 216 }), 500);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <YouTube
                apiKey   = {config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY}
                ref      = {item => this.player = item}
                videoId  = {getVideoId(uri)}
                controls = {1}
                onReady  = {this.handleReady}
                style    = {{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: height }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

It worked for me, but still there is a known issue which is that if resumed from a full screen, the screen is not auto oriented.